# 'Czech'/'Swiss' to refer to the country?

Tags: word-usage, geography

An increasing number of my friends in India and the United Kingdom use 'Czech' to refer to the Czech Republic (and a smaller number do the same with saying 'Swiss' for Switzerland). When politely pointed out to that 'Czechia' is an official short form with official backing, some of them point out that 'Czech' enjoys wider popularity than 'Czechia' in their circles, and also this [beer label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzLNy.png).

While the full names of the countries are, admittedly, tedious to pronounce every time, I do not believe that a contraction of the country name to what is effectively an adjective is grammatically well-founded. My questions to you all would be:

1) Do you observe similar trends in your surroundings?

2) Is there a grammatical basis to it that I am missing?

Comment: Hello Raghav, welcome to EL&U. You and I don't live in British and Indian, we live in Britain and India. British and Indian are adjectives describing us, the governments, and other characteristics of our countries. Similarly the inhabitants, institutions and so on of Switzerland and the Czech Republic (or Czechia) are called Swiss and Czech respectively. I have no idea why Pilsner Urquell give their address as Pilsner, Czech on their labels but suspect that it might have more to do with graphics and space than linguistics. I'd call the countries Switzerland and The Czech Republic myself.

Comment: Any place worth speaking about has nicknames. Very few people will say *The United States of America* in conversation. It’s typically *the States*. Formation of nicknames is not subject to strict grammatical rules.